# Angular-js doesnt work when I add "ng-controller"

Tags: angularjs

I am new to web development, trying to learn angularjs, and got stuck at very first step, this code works fine when I remove `ng-controller` but in this condition the browser shows `Hello, {{name}}`.

What am I doing wrong?

**index.html**

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl" >
    <head >
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta character="uft-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, {{name}}</h1>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    </body>
  </html>
```

**controller.js**

```javascript
  function AppCtrl($scope)
  {
    $scope.name: "world";
  }
```

Comment: Can you please provide what the question is and/or error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling module named `app` which you didn't declared.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl" >
```

If you provide module name then controller have to bind with that module.

To assign a value you have to use `=` not `:`

```
$scope.name: "world";
```

Try Like this

```
$scope.name= "world";
```

Moreover Global controller isn't allowed from `1.3.x`

Try like this

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.name= "world";
});
```

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/L38ts6v0/)</kbd>

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but I have tried doing this, it still doesn't work, what else could be the problem in this?

Comment: Hi, it works now, thank you very much, you the real MVP.

Comment: i read (yesterday) on official doc that making 'var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller(..) ' is bad practice. better to do : 'angular.module("app", []); angular.module("app").controller();'